# time log in database for users

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Hi guys I have been trying to solve my problem i want to observe the users log in and log out time in the system so I decided to create a separate table like user table and log time table in the user table there is a username , password and the other table which is time log table has timelog_in, timelog_out and the foreign key of user_IDno which is referred to the user table i can insert the user log in time but when the time that the user log out i dont know anymore what to do it's hard to update a row when the cardinality of the table is one to many it's hard to find what column will i use to update the log out time of timelog table

This is the table for users

```
---------------------------
user_IDno | username | userpassword
---------------------------
```

This is the table for time log for users

```
---------------------------
timelog_IDno | timelog_in | timelog_out | user_IDno
---------------------------
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Why would you log the users password? That seems very un-secure.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i am using mysql workbench

Comment: @Igor the users time log in and out is what i'm monitoring not their password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there should be multiple entries in your log table for a particular user for a particular day. At the time of log_out you nedd to check if there is an entry for that particular user with a timelog_in woth out timelog_out. if so you have to update the entry.

```
IF EXISTS  (SELECT 1 
      FROM UserTable u
            JOIN userLogInfo i
                on u.[user_IDno]=i.[user_IDno]
       WHERE user_IDno =@user -- user you wanted to update the info
                   AND timelog_in is not null and timelog_out is null)

 THEN 

  /* Your update query*/

ELSE 
 /* Your insert query*/
```

Comment: i'm pleased that you understand my problem i will try to analyze the code you gave

Comment: can you explain the 1 and what is it for ?

Comment: IF condition will return 1 if  there is a user exists in your userlogin info with out log out information. then we have to update that particular user,else you need to enter a new entry..

Comment: ah ok so what about @user?

Comment: if you are updating your login entry against a particular user.. you can mention the user id there..

Comment: so the " timelog_in is not null and timelog_out is null " will determine the user's current because one user can have multiple entries in time log table right ? the purpose of that is to not confuse the queries which is the user_IDno because it will have a redundant user_IDno in time log table